# Python - How to create for multiple user input error handling?

Tags: python, error-handling, user-input

I'm new to python and I was trying to create an error handling for multiple users input. I made the code as the following.
`

```
#load and filter dataset
import pandas as pd

CITY_DATA = {'Chicago' : 'chicago.csv',
            'New York City':'new_york_city.csv',
            'Washington':'washington.csv'}

#filtering dataset
def get_filters ():

    city_options = ['Chicago','New York City','Washington'.title()]
    month_options = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','November','December','all'.title()]
    day_options = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday','all']

    while True:
        city = input('\nInsert name of the city to analyze! (Chicago, New York City, Washington)\n'.title())
        if city in city_options :
            break
        else:
            print('Your choice is not available. Please try again')

    while True:
        month = input('\nInsert month to filter by or "all" to apply no month filter! (January, February, etc.)\n'.title())
        if month in month_options :
            break
        else:
            print('Your choice is not available. Please try again')

    while True:
        day = input('\nInsert day of the week to filter by or "all" to apply no day filter! (Monday, Tuesday, etc.)\n'.title())
        if day in day_options :
            break
        else:
            print('Your choice is not available. Please try again')

    return city, month, day
```

But I believe there is a simpler way for this or maybe create a function? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could wrap all of it in one single function receiving question and error as string, and the list to iterate and find if the input is valid

Answer (score 0):

You can use the try/except statements and loop once for all of three inputs instead of looping again and again. Here is what I came up with. If it doesn't help, happy to delete it.

```
def get_filters():
    city_options, month_options, day_options = ['Chicago','New York City','Washington'.title()], ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','November','December','all'.title()], ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday','all'.title()]
    while True:
        try:
            city = city_options.index(input('\nInsert name of the city to analyze! (Chicago, New York City, Washington)\n'.title()))
            month = month_options.index(input('\nInsert month to filter by or "all" to apply no month filter! (January, February, etc.)\n'.title()))
            day = day_options.index(input('\nInsert day of the week to filter by or "all" to apply no day filter! (Monday, Tuesday, etc.)\n'.title()))
            return city_options[city], month_options[month], day_options[day]
        except ValueError:
            print ("Your previous choice is not available. Please try again")
print (get_filters())
```

Answer (score 0):

A little refactored version of your solution. Not sure whether this is of huge help.

```
def get_valid_input(input_msg, options):
    while True:
        entered_value = input(input_msg)
        if entered_value in options:
            break
        else:
            print('Your choice is not available. Please try again')
            continue

def get_filters():
    city_options = ['Chicago', 'New York City', 'Washington'.title()]
    month_options = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'November',
                     'December', 'all'.title()]
    day_options = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'all']

    city_input_msg = 'Insert name of the city to analyze! (Chicago, New York City, Washington): '
    get_valid_input(city_input_msg, city_options)

    month_input_msg = 'Insert month to filter by or "all" to apply no month filter! (January, February, etc.): '
    get_valid_input(month_input_msg, month_options)

    day_input_msg = 'Insert day of the week to filter by or "all" to apply no day filter! (Monday, Tuesday, etc.): '
    get_valid_input(day_input_msg, day_options)

    return city, month, day
```